# Updating mpld3 figure with JSON data

Tags: python, d3.js, mpld3

I've been playing around with mpld3 plotting and am trying to figure out a good way of updating the generated mpld3 plots by supplying a new JSON serialized dictionary. Let's say I've generated my mpld3 plot using some templating engine:

```
var json_data = {{ mpld3 json serialized using mpld3.fig_to_dict() }}
mpld3.draw_figure("fig01", json_data);
```

Now I've added a slider with a callback which is meant to update the entire figure using a new JSON generated using the `mpld3.fig_to_dict()` call. This [PR](https://github.com/jakevdp/mpld3/pull/237) on mpld3's Github demonstrates how to update and animate individual line elements using a slider but is there any simple way to simply update the entire figure by supplying new json data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the best way to update the entire figure is to remove everything and start fresh.  In terms of your code above:

```
var json_data = {{ mpld3 json serialized using mpld3.fig_to_dict() }};
d3.select("#fig01").selectAll("*").remove();
mpld3.draw_figure("fig01", json_data);
```

Here is [a little example gist](https://gist.github.com/aflaxman/b585bc759ac366bada7a).

Comment: I figured as much, I realize it's a bit much for me to expect mpld3 to magically figure out which elements to update, delete etc. Redrawing probably remains my only options. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I wish that it would, and I invite you to [add a feature request about it](https://github.com/jakevdp/mpld3/issues).  Unfortunately, I think it will be a bit complicated to implement.